# PHP Pdo: selecting record out database

Tags: php, mysql

I got this problem with my website (builded in php(pdo)). If I want here 1 thing out of the database I get all of them and not just 1. As you can see the 2 "onderwerp" are getting showed but I only wanted 1 of them for example the first one.

The code for this is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="well dash-box">
   <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
    <h5><a href="https://google.nl"> hoi</a></h5>
     <?php
      $toppics = $app->get_topics();
      $i = 4;
      foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
      echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
      }
      ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And now I want it to show 1 not all of them but I dont get it done

The 2 things with the dots are out of the database:
[image]

The database where the things behind the dots came from:
[image]

My function:

```
public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;

}
```

So what I want: I want to be abble to select one out of the database, but limit is not what I am looking for. I need to be abble to select the second record en later the 4e or something

Comment: just limit it to one row `LIMIT` clause and get the first row

Comment: But what if I want to select the second one and after that the 4e one? then limit doesnt work?

Comment: Once again you're doing the same mistake. Asking about one thing but adding more important info in comments. Please, __don't__.

Comment: There's no `:ledenpagina_id` in the query. Why are you binding that parameter?

Comment: Maybe you need to add `WHERE id = :ledenpagina_id` to the query?

Comment: Am I missing something, or are both functions the same?

Comment: @Barmar the `:ledenpagina_id` you just need to ignore it does nothing yet

Comment: It should be causing an error. PDO doesn't let you bind a nonexistent parameter.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If you don't want to select a specific ID, how do you know which record you want to select?

Comment: What is `$this->database->bind()` and `$this->database->resultset()`? Those aren't PDO methods.

Comment: @Barmar ignore the `bind` I can delete it its nothing yet and the `resultset` is showing the results out of the db and yes I want to select a specific ID the `onderwerp_id`

Comment: If you want to select a specific ID, use `WHERE id = ...`

Comment: @Barmar if you do it that way tho you need to make several `functions`? or am I wrong?

Comment: Make the ID a parameter to the function.

Comment: @Barmar I am not really getting what you mean with that? can you explain yourself with a example?

Comment: `function get_topic($topic_id) { ... }`. Then use `$topic_id` in `bindParam()`.

Comment: Well i am still not really getting it :3 but I hope this person does himself. maybe it would be nice for him to do it in his code like what does he need to change to this code: `<?php
      $toppics = $app->get_topics();
      $i = 4;
      foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
      echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
      }
      ?>`
And maybe do it as an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @Barmar ^^^^ forgot the tagg